# Redirect visual flow to external URL

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, url, pagereference

Good day Everyone I have created a flow which I embed inside visual force page. After the flow process, I want to redirect the page to external url like 'www.google.com'. The problem is that encounter an error saying

```
Invalid Page Redirection
The page you attempted to access has been blocked due to a redirection to an outside website or an improperly coded link or button. Please contact your salesforce.com Administrator for assistance. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.
```

Can you please explain the cause of this error and how to fix this? Below is some part of code. Thank you

VF Page:

```
<flow:interview name="sample_flow" interview="{!myFlow}" finishLocation="{!OID}" />
```

Class:

```
        public PageReference getOID(){
        String oppId = '';
        oppId = getmyID();
        system.debug('mOPP : '+oppId);
        List<Opportunity> listOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
        List<String> listOpptoCloseWon = new List<String>();//Jan 18

        if(String.isNotBlank(oppId)){
            listOpp = [Select Id, Name, AS_Product__r.Name, AS_Product__c from Opportunity where Id = :getmyID()];
            if( listOpp[0].AS_Product__r.Name.tolowerCase().trim() == 'student'){

                PageReference p = new PageReference('www.google.com');
                p.setRedirect(true); 
                return p;  
            }else{ // if not student

                PageReference p = new PageReference('/apex/PaymentPage?oppId='+getmyID());
                p.setRedirect(true);
                return p;
            }
        }else{
            system.debug('kELSE !!!');
            PageReference p = new PageReference('/apex/PaymentPage?oppId='+getmyID());
            p.setRedirect(true);
            return p;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in [Salesforce Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_vf_finish.htm) you cannot set an external url as the finishLocation.

Comment: Here's a [more current doc ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_finishlocation.htm)